# How to make Cython use the correct shared library?

Tags: python, cython

I am currently trying to write a wrapper for a C library. It works perfectly locally, but has to be run on a remote server on which I do not have admin privileges.
A compiled version of the C library and include files is available in a known folder that I will denote hereafter as /correct/folder.
I first tried using a setup.py, specifying the library location by setting the relevant parameters, i.e.

```
setup(
ext_modules = cythonize([Extension("frlib", ["frlib.py"],
    include_dirs=["/correct/folder/include"],
    library_dirs=["/correct/folder/lib"],
    libraries=["<name>"])])
)
```

This is where it gets messy. There is already an existing (unsatisfactory) python package making use of the library, which has its owned compiled version of the library, which is an outdated one. Many of the `sysconfig` variables point to the folder containing this outdated library, so when I use setup.py, the gcc commands unvariably link to the incorrect one (some `-L/wrong/folder` argument is passed).
To bypass this, I ran the gcc commands myself, removing all the references to /wrong/folder. When I run the `ldd <name>.so` command, I see the correct folder listed for the C library ; however it also appears in the "unused runtime libraries" in `ldd -u <name>.so`. And when I import the Python library and uses the C command for getting the version of the library, it shows to be the wrong version.

I am assuming that it must come from an environment variable used by cython or gcc, but really cannot understand when it comes into play. I added both `-L/correct/folder` and `-Wl,-rpath-link,/correct/folder` to gcc, so this should not be overridden, right ? Also, the correct path is in the $LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Could this appear when Cython transforms the .py into .c ? Are there tools other than ldd that could help me diagnose this ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, managed to do it (always after posting the question, of course...).

Had to use `-Wl,-rpath,/correct/folder` instead of `-Wl,-rpath-link,/correct/folder`.